# run function if success ($.ajax) has 200 status code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-codes

I would like to use `success` and run function only if has 200 status code
I have see only this example:

```
 $.ajax ({
   success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
     external();
   }
 )};
```

But i never see a really code example
i would like the if status code is 200 is run an external function

P.S. before i tried to use easy success (without arguments) and error, but error worked also if the external file was ok..

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `success` event is called when the request succeeds ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). The `textStatus` parameter should contain the string `'200'` or any other status number your server returned.

I hope the code you posted is partial: I don't see the url, method, etc. which should be passed as parameters to `$.ajax`.

Comment: Yes yes is partial :) so i can write "success: function(textStatus)" and inside put "if (textStatus == '200') { external() }" ???

Comment: No; sincet `textStatus` is the second parameter, you need to provide (at least) the data parameter as well (you don't need to use it): `success: function(data, status) {if(status === '200') {console.log('yay!');}}`